# Source List bound to NSTreeController not showing data

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I have a Source List bound to an NSTreeController. The tree controller has content bound to my view controller with Model keyPath = sidebarItems, which is an NSArray of SidebarItem objects.

My NSOutlineView has content bound to the tree controller with Controller Key = arrangedObjects, and both dataSource and delegate connected to my view controller.

I have extended my view controller for protocols NSOutlineViewDataSource and NSOutlineViewDelegate, and implemented viewFor, isGroupItem, numberOfChildrenOfItem, child and shouldSelectItem.

I have my content array filled with static SidebarItem.

The problem I'm encountering is none of these functions are called, and so no item is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, my content array had to be declared dynamic for NSTreeController to have access to it.